# finding a table in a text file and printing it

Tags: python

i have text file containing the following data:

```
 EMethod_sel="ID"
 Sel_Ele_Search_Pattern="*D=30*" Sel_Ele_Label_Toggle=OFF
 Eid=SHOW_OK
 All 171665 elements are suitable
 ShowFE/XROT
 ECHConnect
 ShowFE/ZROT
 ShowFE/YROT
 Asca
 ShowFE/YROT
 Asca
 ShowFE/XROT
 EMSameNorm/ALL
 ShowFE/ZROT
 ECHPenetra ShellThick=Shell-Thickness, ScaleFac=0.9, SetID=9999
 * 20 coincident elements
 ECHCoincid
 Summary
 * O B J E C T   ( FE )           Total    Min-ID    Max-ID Show/Defi
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Nodes                         225965         1    226932    225785
 * Elements                      171665         1    198299    171665
 * Materials                          2       100       101         2
 * Properties                        46         1   1000009        46
 * Element Sets                      83         1     10000
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------
 * O B J E C T   ( PART )         Total    Min-LV    Max-LV
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Parts                              1         0         0
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------
 * O B J E C T   ( GEO )          Total   Minimum   Maximum      Show
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------
 * No GEO - Objects found
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------
 Asca
 ShowFE/XROT
 ShowFE/YROT
 EMSameNorm/
 ShowFE/ZROT
 Inertia EGeo_dist_sel=0.1 ETilt_angle_sel=30 EProperty_limits_sel=ON
 ELayer_limits_sel=ON ESame_face_IDs_only_sel=OFF
 Eid=SHOW
```

i need to find if it has any table or not and if it is there it should print it and the table length may vary. so how can we do this ?
is there any module that can do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Since the lines `Summary` and `Asca` mark start and end of a table, the following code can be used.

```
with open("in.txt") as input:
    intable = False
    for line in input:
        if line.strip() == "Summary":
            intable = True
        if line.strip() == "Asca":
            intable = False
        if intable and line.strip().startswith("*"):
            print(line.strip())
```

Output:

```
* O B J E C T   ( FE )           Total    Min-ID    Max-ID Show/Defi
* ------------------------------------------------------------------
* Nodes                         225965         1    226932    225785
* Elements                      171665         1    198299    171665
* Materials                          2       100       101         2
* Properties                        46         1   1000009        46
* Element Sets                      83         1     10000
* ------------------------------------------------------------------
* O B J E C T   ( PART )         Total    Min-LV    Max-LV
* ------------------------------------------------------------------
* Parts                              1         0         0
* ------------------------------------------------------------------
* O B J E C T   ( GEO )          Total   Minimum   Maximum      Show
* ------------------------------------------------------------------
* No GEO - Objects found
* ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: yeah thanks a lot the *20 coincident elements is not the first line

Comment: If you can tell us more ways to identify a table, I can improve my answer.

Comment: the table is only from summary to Asca, but the line may be different in different file, can you help me now

Comment: i've tried the code but it prints all the * marked sentences but i just want the table